# Column of numbers. If one of the numbers is equal to another number in the column, excluding itself, put a "T" in front of it

Tags: google-sheets

I'm so close to getting it. I've tried a couple things. My wheelhouse is python. Unfortunately Excel is not my forte.

```
=IF(OR(U2=(U3:U32)),"T"&U2,U2)
```

First attempt.
If `U2` is in `U3:U32`, put a `T` in front of `U2`, else `U2`.

```
=IF(OR(countif(U3:U32,U2)),"T"&U2,U2)
```

Second attempt.
Trying to compare all the other numbers using `countif` to `U2`, if `U2` exists in `U3:U32`, put a `T` in front of `U2`, else `U2` itself.

Any quick solutions out there?

Comment: Welcome. Can you please share a link to a test sheet with expected results? It would be great help.

Answer (score 1):

This formula takes a range containing strings or numbers and returns an output that has "T" prepended whenever an element occurs more than once. This is my understanding of the question:
`=IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A$11,A2)>1,"T"&A2,A2)`

If you want to have the input replaced itself automatically, you have to work with a script that triggers on edit.

[image: Solution]